# High-Score Leaderboard system issue

Tags: java, leaderboard

I made a game on android studio where the user must collect as many points as they can before they die. I've set up a leaderboard system so if the user gets a highscore they can enter their name and it will display it on the leaderboard. I have a gameover screen that appears when the user dies and in that screen I have a button for the leaderboard screen. But the only problem is that the user has to click on that button to go into the leaderboard screen to enter in their name if they got a highscore. I want it so where if the user gets a highscore he is automatically put into the leaderboard screen when he dies rather then the gameover screen.

So my question is does anybody have any idea on how to make the user go into the leaderboard class if they get a highscore rather than the game over class?

I've tried making a static int "m" in my leaderboard class and having it under each of the 1st, 2nd and 3rd places that the user can be placed under and said if (score > m) then go to leaderboard screen but I realised this won't work because I have m equal to 1,2 and 3

My code:

Leaderboard Class

```
if(score > scoreSP){
            scoreTB = scoreSB;
            scoreSB = scoreSP;
            editorr.putInt("scoreSB", scoreSB);
            editorrr.putInt("scoreTB", scoreTB);
            scoreSP = score;
            editor.putInt("scoreSP", scoreSP);
            editor.commit();
            editorr.commit();
            editorrr.commit();
            scoreName = 1;
            m = 1;

 }else
        if(score > scoreSB && score <= scoreSP){
            scoreTB = scoreSB;
            editorrr.putInt("scoreTB", scoreTB);
            scoreSB = score;
            editorr.putInt("scoreSB", scoreSB);
            editorr.commit();
            editorrr.commit();
            scoreName = 2;
            m =2;

  }else
        if(score <= scoreSB && score > scoreTB){
            scoreTB = score;
            editorrr.putInt("scoreTB", scoreTB);
            editorrr.commit();
            scoreName = 3;
            m = 3;
}
```

Game Engine class

```
if (lives == 0) {
            gameState = 2;
            GameActivity.end(score);

            if(score > Leaderboard.m){
                GameActivity.endd(score);
            }
        }
```

Game Activity class

```
static void end(int score){
    AppConstants.firstLeaderboard = true;
    Context context = AppConstants.gameActivityContext;
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, GameOver.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    AppConstants.score = score;
    context.startActivity(intent);
    ((Activity) context).finish();
}
static void endd(int score){
    Context context = AppConstants.gameActivityContext;
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Leaderboard.class);
    intent.putExtra("score", AppConstants.score);
    context.startActivity(intent);
    ((Activity) context).finish();
}
```

GameActivity.end(score); brings me to the gameover screen and  GameActivity.endd(score); brings me to the leaderboard screen.

I have also tried changing the position of the two of them but that doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the rest is correct, you need to fix this:

```
if (lives == 0) {
            gameState = 2;
            GameActivity.end(score);

            if(score > Leaderboard.m){
                GameActivity.endd(score);
            }
        }
```

To this:

```
if (lives == 0) {
            gameState = 2;

            if(score > Leaderboard.m){
                GameActivity.endd(score);
            } else GameActivity.end(score);
        }
```

Comment: The TO stated that m is not the score but the rank (? - I haven't quite figured out yet waht SB, TB or SP actually stand for) on the leaderboard, so its probably better to store the minimum required score to qualify for the leaderboard instead and do the rank calculation later.

Comment: Yes, I missed this. You definitely need to store best score in some available variable if you want to decide which screen you want to show.

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a go